# Validating a BST

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, inorder

Just one quick question regarding validating a BST via In Order Traversal

```
public boolean isValidBST(TreeNode root) {
   if (root == null) return true;
   Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();
   TreeNode pre = null;
   while (root != null || !stack.isEmpty()) {
      while (root != null) {
         stack.push(root);
         root = root.left;
      }
      root = stack.pop();
      if(pre != null && root.val <= pre.val) return false;
      pre = root;
      root = root.right;
   }
   return true;
}
```

At risk of sounding silly, what is the point of the second last line `root = root.right` since doesn't it immediatly get reassigned to `root = stack.pop()` right after in the next iteration of the while loop?

Comment: The inner while loop will descend via left children first.

Comment: I know. My question was what is the point of root = root.right?

Comment: You have to find the right children somehow.

Comment: But doesn't it get replaced immediately when you declare root = stack.pop()?

Comment: Only when it's null.

Comment: Sorry if I sound really dumb, but which line states that root = root.right will only kick in if root is null?

Answer (score 1):

> what is the point of the second last line root = root.right

if you not access the right child of the node, you are actually processing same node again and again and again .. and so on, you will always end up with infinite loop.

> doesn't it immediatly get reassigned to root = stack.pop() right after in the next iteration of the while loop?

NO.

```
 while (root != null) {
     stack.push(root);
     root = root.left;
  }
  root = stack.pop();
```

Till now you are at the left most node of the tree. It will always points to same node until you are traverse the right child of the current node.

Just look at the following:

```
        4
       / 
      3 
     / 
    2
   / \
   1  0
```

After the inner while loop, your stack will be like: 4->3->2->1
It will always loop-back between 2 and 1 node unless until you are visiting right child of 1 and 2 respectively.

For that reason,

```
root = root.right;
```

is very very important to terminate the loop and to traverse all the nodes of the tree.

Good night from India!

Comment: Sorry for asking again but let's say I have the following tree:

//////2

//1 /////3

So after the inner while loop the stack looks like [2 , 1]

We pop 1 off the stack so root = 1.

root = root.right so root = null.

While Loop runs again:

Stack is just [ 2 ]

root = stack.pop() so root = 2.

root = root.right so root = 3.

Is this flow correct?